# Change width parameter of Trail Renderer with audio spectrum C# Script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I am trying to find a way to dynamically change the width parameter of a trail renderer with the audio spectrum from an audio file. I have successfully been able change the scale of the game object, but not the actual width parameter of the trail renderer itself. Here is the code that works to dynamically change the scale of using the audio spectrum. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks

Code to change scale using audio spectrum:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class trailTest : MonoBehaviour {
public float width = 5.0f;
public bool useCurve = true;
private TrailRenderer tr;
public int numberOfObjects = 1;


void Start ()
{
    tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer> ();
    tr.material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Sprites/Default"));
}

void Update ()
{
    AnimationCurve curve = new AnimationCurve ();
    if (useCurve) {
        curve.AddKey (0.0f, 0.0f);
        curve.AddKey (1.0f, 1.0f);
    } else {
        curve.AddKey (0.0f, 1.0f);
        curve.AddKey (1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    float [] spectrum = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData (1024, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
        Vector3 previousScale = tr.transform.localScale;
        previousScale.y = Mathf.Lerp (previousScale.y, spectrum [i] * 80, Time.deltaTime * 30);
        tr.transform.localScale = previousScale;

      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Modify `tr.width` not `tr.transform`....

Comment: I can use the parameter `startWidth` or  `endWidth`

Comment: That's what I meant. XXXWidth property.

Comment: I am getting the error now `Type float does not contain a definition for localScale and no extension method localScale of type float could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` New to c# scripting so I am in the midst of learning how to de-bug. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class trailTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TrailRenderer trailRenderer;
    public GameObject [] trailerbaby;
    public int numberOfObjects = 1;
    void Start ()
    {
        trailRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<TrailRenderer> ();
        float startWidth = trailRenderer.startWidth;
        float endWidth = trailRenderer.endWidth;
        trailRenderer.startWidth = 1f;
        trailRenderer.endWidth = 1f;
        Debug.Log ("Start width: " + startWidth + '\t' + "End width: " + endWidth);

        trailerbaby = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("trailerbaby");

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        trailRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<TrailRenderer> ();
        float startWidth = trailRenderer.startWidth;
        float endWidth = trailRenderer.endWidth;
        Debug.Log ("Start width: " + startWidth + '\t' + "End width: " + endWidth);
        float [] spectrum = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData (1024, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            //Vector3 previousPosition = trailerbaby [i].transform.localPosition;
            trailRenderer.startWidth = Mathf.Lerp (trailRenderer.startWidth, spectrum [i] * 2000, Time.deltaTime * 13000 * 10);
            trailRenderer.endWidth = Mathf.Lerp (trailRenderer.startWidth, spectrum [i] * 2000, Time.deltaTime * 13000 * 10);
            //previousPosition.y = Mathf.Lerp (previousPosition.y, spectrum [i] * 2000, Time.deltaTime * 13000);
            //trailerbaby [i].transform.localPosition = previousPosition;

        }

    }
}
```